# change dd/mm/yy date format to yy/mm/dd using php

Tags: php

I'm having date 20/12/2001 in this formate . i need  to convert in  following format  2001/12/20 using php .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$var = explode('/',$date);
$var = array_reverse($var);
$final = implode('/',$var);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your safest bet

```
<?php
$input = '20/12/2001';
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/',$input);
$output= "$year/$month/$day";
echo $output."\n";
```

Add validation as needed/desired.  You input date isn't a known valid date format, so [strToTime](http://php.net/strToTime) won't work.

Alternately, you could use [mktime](https://www.php.net/mktime) to create a date once you had the day, month, and year, and then use [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the date string from somewhere else (as opposed to generating it yourself) and need to reformat it:

```
$date = '20/12/2001';
preg_replace('!(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)!', '$3/$2/$1', $date);
```

If you need the date for other purposes and are running PHP >= 5.3.0:

```
$when = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
$when->format('Y/m/d');
// $when can be used for all sorts of things
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually parse it.

1. Split/explode text on `"/"`.
2. Check you have three elements.
3. Do other basic checks that you have day in `[0]`, month in `[1]` and year in `[2]` (that mostly means checking they're numbers and int he correct range)
4. Put them together again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date("Y/m/d");
```

I believe that should work... Someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: this is only get the date . I need to convert it anyway thanks for the response

Comment: If you have it always in the format d/m/y then you could parse the info and just rearrange. I thought you meant you were calling the date in that order, but wanted to know how to call it in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sscanf](http://www.php.net/sscanf) in order to parse and reorder the parts of the date:

```
$theDate = '20/12/2001';
$newDate = join(sscanf($theDate, '%3$2s/%2$2s/%1$4s'), '/');

assert($newDate == '2001/12/20');
```

Or, if you are using PHP 5.3, you can use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/DateTime) object to do the converting:

```
$theDate = '20/12/2001';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $theDate);
$newDate = $date->format('Y/m/d');

assert($newDate == '2001/12/20');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = Date::CreateFromFormat('20/12/2001', 'd/m/Y');
$newdate = $date->format('Y/m/d');
```